# WordPress Menus : Remove classes from ul for third level

Tags: wordpress, wp-nav-walker, wp-nav-menu-item

I am using [Bootstrap nav walker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php)

for creating WordPress menus.
What it creates

```
<ul id="primary-menu" class="navbar-nav ml-lg-auto font-weight-bold">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-119">
       <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-119">
         <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-119">
```

Now I don't want to add classes on third & fourth level of UL. How I can do it?Is it possible without JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write script for third & fourth level of menu.

```
if ( $args->has_children && $depth === 0){ $class_names .= ' dropdown'; } elseif($args->has_children && $depth == 3){ $class_names .= ' '; }
```

Try something like that.